# How to write the value of a constant into another variable using laravel

Tags: constants, laravel-7

I'm new to PHP and laravel and I'm doing a project to improve my knowledge, but I have a huge problem, because I can't write the value of a constant in a variable to save it in the database.

My constant file looks like this: (It is inside the Config folder inside the app)

```
<?php

return [

    'STATUS' => [
        'PENDING' => 0,
        'ACTIVE' => 1,
        'FAILED' => 2,
        'OFF' => 3
    ],

    'ACCESSES' => [
        'PROVIDER' => 1,
        'REQUEST' => 2
    ]
];
```

There in my controller is as follows:

```
use App\Config\constants;

 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \app\Http\Requests\requestPrestador  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(requestPrestador $request)
    {   
        
       // Taking the value of the constant
        $ status = \ Config :: get ('constants.STATUS.PENDENTE');
        $ access = \ Config :: get ('constants.ACESSOS.PRESTADOR');

        dd ($ status);

        $ address = $ this-> objEndereco-> create ([
            'CEP' => $ request-> providerCep,
            'ADDRESS' => $ request-> ProviderAddress,
            'NUMERO' => $ request-> providerNumero,
            'COMPLEMENT' => $ request-> providerComplemento,
            'BAIRRO' => $ request-> neighborhood provider,
            'CITY_ID' => $ request-> CITY provider,
            'STATE_ID' => $ request-> state provider,
        ]);
        // Recording the address id
        $ idEndereco = $ address-> id;
        
        $ certificate = $ this-> objCertificate-> create ([
            'CERTIFICATE' => $ request-> certificateFormacao-> store ('certificates')
        ]);
        // Writing the certificate id
        $ idCertificate = $ certificate-> id;

        $ antecedente = $ this-> objAntecedente-> create ([
            'BACKGROUND' => $ request-> background-> store ('background')
        ]);
        // Recording the criminal record id
        $ idAntedecente = $ antecedent-> id;

        // dd ($ idAntedecente);

        $ provider = $ this-> objPrestador-> create ([
            'NAME' => $ request-> providerName,
            'CPF' => $ request-> providerCPF,
            'PHONE' => $ request-> providerPhone ,
            'DT_NASCIMENTO' => $ request-> providerNascimento,
            'SEX' => $ request-> gender,
            'EMAIL' => $ request-> providerEmail ,
            'PASSWORD' => $ request-> providerPassword,
            'TRAINING' => $ request-> training,
            'ID_CERTIFICADO' => $ idCertificate,
            'BACKGROUND ID' => $ previousID,
            'ID_ENDERECO' => $ idIDereco,
            'ACCESS_ID' => $ access,
            'STATUS' => $ status
        ]);
```

Ai on the return of the dd is coming null;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKw03.png)

Comment: This is still unclear (and the last sentence is still untranslated). Can you please still [edit] to clarify what the result should be? Or maybe delete this and ask at [pt.so].

Comment: @KauanHenrique please also edit your comments (in the code). That way your question will be clear to any potential answers....

Comment: @tripleee and now? Is correct?

Comment: if you want to use the config system the file would be in the `config` folder at the root of the project, not in `app` ... and you would get the configuration value as `config('constants.STATUS.PENDING')` ... though i imagine you probably want to use something more like classes with constants you access

Comment: @lagbox yes, i would like to take the value of a constant and save it in a variable, as i would do in this case?

Comment: I managed to solve it, the file was in the wrong folder, I changed and solved it, thanks